# KeyError: column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I load a dataset like this:

```
df_performance = pd.read_csv('.local.csv')
df_performance.head()
```

The data in the csv file is already displayed as a table. The printed head is just like a normal one. However, when I try to run this snippet:

```
df_performance["Day"] = ""

df_performance.loc['Day'] = [str(x) for x in df_performance.loc["From"]]
```

I get such errors:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'From'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

I also tried printing the names of the columns, and I know that 'From' exists. Then why do I get such an error?

```
for col_name in df_performance:
    print(col_name)
```

```
    From           Cost   helps
0   Jan 1, 2020      3      4
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no extra character (e.g. space) ? Print all names surrounded by quotes, for example, to determine that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use `loc` it selects index by label, not column name. So if not label exist it raise error:

```
df_performance.loc['Day'] = [str(x) for x in df_performance.loc["From"]]
```

So it seems need convert column to strings:

```
#by list comprehension
df_performance['Day'] = [str(x) for x in df_performance["From"]]

#by function
df_performance['Day'] = df_performance["From"].astype(str)
```